# using boost::geometry, project a new point using distance and azimuth

Tags: c++, boost-geometry

using a starting lon/lat point, a distance, and azimuth, how can I get the coordinates of a new point? Ideally, this would be implemented using wgs84.

```
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/distance.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>

// The inverse of what I'm trying to do
boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> a(0, 0);
boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> b(1, 0);
double distance_between_points = boost::geometry::distance(a, b);

// what I'm trying to do
boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> point_a(0, 0);
double distance_km{111.32};
double azimuth_deg{90};
// point_c should be approximatly (0, 1)
// this is not a real function signature for distance
boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> point_c = boost::geometry::distance(point_a, distance_km, azimuth_deg);
```

Comment: Hi - did you find an answer to this problem ?

Comment: Have not. There is a python solution here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/174766/60045 that uses **pygc**. The **pygc** source code https://github.com/axiom-data-science/pygc/blob/master/pygc/gc.py is a single file and is mostly just vincenty which is in boost at `boost::geometry::strategy::vincenty`.  I think you could do the same in boost following the **pygc** as an example.

Answer (score 0):

There is no algorithm for computing what you want in Boost Geometry currently but you can use (as a workaround) some internal formulas (that is why they are ugly ;)

The following example solves the [direct geodesic problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid#Solution_of_the_direct_and_inverse_problems) for your input on WGS84 (default spheroid in geographic coordinate system in Boost Geometry).

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/geometry/geometry.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;


int main()
{
    using point = bg::model::point
    <
        double, 2,
        bg::cs::geographic<bg::degree>
    >;

    point a(0, 0);
    point b(1, 0);
    double distance_between_points = boost::geometry::distance(a, b);

    point point_a(0, 0);
    double azimuth_deg{90};

    using direct_t = typename bg::strategy::andoyer::template direct
        <double, true, false, false, false>;

    // direct formula expect input in radians
    auto dir_r = direct_t::apply(bg::get_as_radian<0>(point_a),
                                 bg::get_as_radian<1>(point_a),
                                 distance_between_points,
                                 azimuth_deg * bg::math::d2r<double>(),
                                 bg::srs::spheroid<double>());

    // and returns input in radians too, so we convert it to display in degrees
    std::cout << dir_r.lon2 * bg::math::r2d<double>()
              << " "
              << dir_r.lat2 * bg::math::r2d<double>()
              << std::endl;

    return 0;

}

//prints: 1 6.16419e-17
```

*Note that this works for version 1.80.0 (but there is no guarantee that this will work in future versions of `boost` since this functionality is not exposed in the interface).*